# Prounouncing the combination "-cy-"

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Is there any word in the English language that contains the letter combination "-cy-" and pronounced with a hard 'c'? 
I find it strange that all the common use words are pronounced with a soft 'c' if the 'c' is followed by a 'y', considering that Middle English pronounced the combination as 'ky'.

Comment: "... considering that Middle English pronounced the combination as 'ky'" -- source?.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (most likely incomplete) list of all the words I found where cy has a hard c:

- [Baccy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/baccy) is pronounced /ˈbæki/.
- [Choccy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/choccy) is pronounced /ˈtʃɒki/.
- [Laccy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/laccy) is pronounced /ˈlaki/.
- [Leccy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leccy) is pronounced /ˈlɛki/.
- [Piccy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/piccy) is pronounced /ˈpɪki/.
- [Placcy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/placcy) is pronounced /ˈplaki/.
- [Talcy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/talcy) is pronounced /ˈtalki/ or /ˈtælki/.
- [Tobaccy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tobaccy) is pronounced /təˈbaki/.

All of these words (except for "talcy") seem to have been formed within the past 200 years. Some words that would have been spelled like this end up with a k added, such as *colicky*.

Comment: Other than *talcy* all have a double-c, though.

Comment: They necessarily have a *k* added on because otherwise the *c* would be soft, a double-c is not.